# Windows Service Bus Read messages without deleting them

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Hy,

is it possible to receive the messages from the service bus without deleting them?
I found the peek() function in the docs but I can't use it with the Windows Service Bus 1.0 API. I tried the following:

```
    //Creates a new copy of SubscriptionClient with specified name and topic path.
    SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient = messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName);
```

But there is only a receive function available which always deletes the messages. In the Service Bus Explorer there is a Option called "Peek all messages" which didn't deletes the messages. Does anybody know how he implements that?

I found a peek function in the docs but I can't use it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.aspx

Best regards

Comment: the code from the service bus explorer is open for you to read, so you can always have a look there to see how Paolo did it.  
Can you tell me why you cannot use the peek function ?

Comment: Hy, yes but this is the Service Bus 2.1 and don't works on Windows Service Bus 1.0. I use the version 1.8. But there is only the exe of the Version in the folder. I saw that he uses in the new version the peek function but it didn't work at my example and I don't know why.

Can you use the peek function with the code example I posted above?

Comment: Hmmm.  Can't remember that Peek was not part of 1.8.  Could be.
I would advise you to upgrade Service Bus to 1.1 if that's possible (then you have AMQP and some other enhancements too).
If you cannot do that, you might try to do a PeekLock receive, without deleting the messages.  (although that sounds a little dirty)

Comment: Hy, yes it's part of 1.8 but I don't have the source code of this version. I already tried the with the ReceiveMode.PeekLock and it didn't work too. All messages are deleated after receiving.

`SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient = messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);`

Comment: Did you abandon the messages ?

Comment: What do you mean with abondon the messages?

Comment: message.Abandon() , this will (in PeekLock mode) leave the message on the queue or subscription